# Return all fields MongoDB Aggregate

Tags: mongodb

I tried searching on here but couldn't really find what I need. I have documents like this:

```
{
    appletype:Granny,
    color:Green,
    datePicked:2015-01-26,
    dateRipe:2015-01-24,
    numPicked:3
},

{
    appletype:Granny,
    color:Green,
    datePicked:2015-01-01,
    dateRipe:2014-12-28,
    numPicked:6
}
```

I would like to return only those apples picked latest, will all fields. I want my query to return me the first document only essentially. When I try to do:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match : { "appletype" : "Granny" } },
    { $sort : { "datePicked" : 1 } },
    { $group : { "_id" : { "appletype" : "$appletype" },
        "datePicked" : { $max : "$datePicked" } },
])
```

It does return me all the apples picked latest, however with only appletype:Granny and datePicked:2015-01-26. I need the remaining fields. I tries using $project and adding all the fields, but it didn't get me what I needed. Also, when I added the other fields to the group, since datePicked is unique, it returned both records.

How can I go about returning all fields, for only the latest datePicked?

Thanks!

Comment: You say "I want my query to return me the first document only essentially". So, you want to get just one document with latest datePicked?

Comment: The collection I'm using is several thousand records long. I would like to get all appleTypes picked on the latest datePicked, returning all fields that make up the "apple" document. So if there were n apples picked on 2014-01-26 (or whatever the latest date happens to be), then return those n records.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds like you want one document for each of the types of apple in your collection and showing the document with the most recent `datePicked` value.

Here is an aggregate query for that:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { "datePicked": -1 },
  { $group: { _id: "$appletype", color: { $first: "$color" }, datePicked: { $first: "$datePicked" }, dateRipe: { $first: "$dateRipe" }, numPicked: { $first: "$numPicked" } } },
  { $project: { _id: 0, color: 1, datePicked: 1, dateRipe: 1, numPicked: 1, appletype: "$_id" } }
])
```

But then based on the aggregate query you've written, it looks like you're trying to get this:

```
db.collection.find({appletype: "Granny"}).sort({datePicked: -1}).limit(1);
```

Comment: How to return everything with project?

Comment: @Qui-GonJinn It's been awhile since I worked in MongoDB. I think there's a way to get `$project` to show everything from a document, but if `$project` comes after a step like `$group`, it can only get what it is given from that previous step.
That's a key thing to understand about aggregate queries in general - each step in the query only gets the data returned from the previous step, it doesn't look back at the collection and pull the original document.